# Click on Button from another application with c#

Tags: c#, api

Click on Button from another application with c#

I need to handle another windows application programatically.

below is my code :

```
       public const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        public const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        /// <summary>
        /// The FindWindow API
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpClassName">the class name for the window to search for</param>
        /// <param name="lpWindowName">the name of the window to search for</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

        /// <summary>
        /// The SendMessage API
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">handle to the required window</param>
        /// <param name="msg">the system/Custom message to send</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">first message parameter</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">second message parameter</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        /// <summary>
        /// The FindWindowEx API
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentHandle">a handle to the parent window </param>
        /// <param name="childAfter">a handle to the child window to start search after</param>
        /// <param name="className">the class name for the window to search for</param>
        /// <param name="windowTitle">the name of the window to search for</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int hwnd = 0;
            IntPtr hwndChild = IntPtr.Zero;

             hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Form22");
            if (hwnd != 0)
            {
// AnotherButton => text button another programm
                hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "AnotherButton");

                 SendMessage((int) hwndChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

        }
```

another dotnet app :

```
  private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = "another Program";
    }
```

But in any event does not occur. Please help if anyone knows how to solve it.

Comment: Have you debugged through? Is the hwnd found ok? How about hwndChild? It would help if you could explain at which point it fails.

Comment: There are a *lot* of things wrong here.  Everything, really, bad pinvoke declarations, bad arguments, not enough error checking, bad messages.  You don't want to write this kind code, use an UI Automation library to get ahead.  Project White is popular.

Comment: You could look into using named pipes instead, which worked fine for an application I worked on, but that may not have the flexibility you need. Check out System.Io.Pipes. Some folks may scream, "No! That's [insert insult]!" but if you just need something working, it's an option.